# oracle sql monthly sum of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that records random daily production data two oil fields:

```
field           Date              Production
fld1         02/01/2013              100
fld2         02/05/2013               50
fld1         02/03/2013               70
fld2         02/06/2013               30
...
fld1         11/31/2014               80
fld2         11/29/2014               70
```

I want to write a sql to generate a report of monthly production for each field:

```
fld1         02/2013            xxxx 
fld1         03/2013            xxxx
....
fld2         02/2013            xxxx
fld2         03/2013            xxxx
```

Can it be done in a single sql? I am relatively new to Oracle analytics.

Comment: Select field , sum(production) from table

Comment: `Select field , sum(production) from table where date between to_date('01012014', 'mmddyyyy') and to_date('31012014', 'mmddyyyy') Group by field` - anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select field, to_char(prod_date,'MM/YYYY') mon, sum(production) total_prod
from data
group by field,  to_char(prod_date,'MM/YYYY')
order by field, to_char(prod_date,'MM/YYYY')
```

Here is the [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/510a2/1)